# OpenCV and OpenGL scale

Tags: opengl, opencv

Based on Opencv tracking I am trying to overlay object in openGL, but I see that OpenCV works on pixel values and OpenGL works on OpenGL units.

My window size for now is 320 x 240.
I know that I will have to define some thing so that synchronization is achieved between tracking and overlay. When I am changing `positiony` in OpenGL function `glTranslatef (positionx, positiony, positionz);` by just 1 pixel *(i.e. 1 OpenGL Unit)* I am getting huge difference in overlay object...

I think the problem is with the synchronization Of Opencv and OpenGL scale....

Comment: Whats wrong with the question !!!!

Comment: Why down vote without any reason.....

Comment: Not sure, seems alright to me - but I have tried to answer your question below. Do let me know if that isn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a screen-aligned orthographic projection to map OpenGL units 1:1 with screen pixels.

```
    glViewport(0,0,320,240);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0,320,0,240,0,1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Still it behaves in the same way as it was before....If you can help me out with some tutorial code I will be highly thankful....